# Error creating a database with Filestream folder path more than 160 symbols

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, filestream

I have a problem during creation or attaching DB with FILESTEAM folder path more than 160 symbols.

*Error: 5135
The path 'C:...length more than 160 symbols....' cannot be used for FILESTREAM files. For information about supported paths, see SQL Server Books Online.*

Does anybody know about this restriction? Does it possible configure this restriction?

Thankyou for your help.

P.S. Here is some definition of FILESTREAM feature http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471497.aspx

Comment: Please provide the FILESTREAM definition? preferably in T-SQL

Comment: some definition of FILESTREAM feature http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471497.aspx

Comment: that's not what i meant. can you script the definition of the FILESTREAM file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer.
SQL Server really have the restriction. And it is not configurable.

[*The number of characters in the complete path name (both file name plus all subdirectories) exceeds the file system limits. The maximum size of the path name depends on your operating system. As a general guideline, long path names greater than 160 characters might cause problems.*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165768%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)